# How can I auto load kernel module on boot in Yocto? (like "insmod /xxx/oo.ko")

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake, nxp-microcontroller

Our system is NXP fsl-image-auto and build with Yocto project.
Now we have a 3rd party ko "apex.ko", rootfs Path is /s32v/apex.ko

This module need load on linux boot, so we add "insmod /s32v/apex.ko" line into rcS.d to do this job.

Can this function be done with Yocto?

I tried "KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD += apex" but it seems can't work.
And I tried "module_do_install()", but bitbake has "make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop. ERROR: oe_runmake failed" error massage.

How can I do this?
Thanks...

Comment: did you try `KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD += "kernel-module-apex"` ?

Answer (score 2):

The way we use to add a kernel module at startup is by adding KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD variable:

```
KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD += "mymodule"
```

But you need to add it in your machine.conf, or in a recipe (not an image), as described in the [documentation](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/singleindex.html#term-KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD):

> You can use the KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD variable anywhere that it can
> be recognized by the kernel recipe or by an out-of-tree kernel module
> recipe (e.g. a machine configuration file, a distribution
> configuration file, an append file for the recipe, or the recipe
> itself).
>
> [...]
>
> Including KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD causes the OpenEmbedded build system
> to populate the /etc/modules-load.d/modname.conf file with the list of
> modules to be auto-loaded on boot. The modules appear one-per-line in
> the file.

Comment: error 404, new yocto doc link: https://docs.yoctoproject.org/singleindex.html#term-KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add prefix to name of your module:

```
 KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD += "module_name"
```

https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html?highlight=kernel_module_autoload#term-KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD

Comment: error 404, new yocto doc link: https://docs.yoctoproject.org/singleindex.html#term-KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD